# How to migrate all images in Magento from version 1.3 to 1.6

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Need some help out there with you.

I have been working on data migration on Magento from version 1.3 to 1.6. Now I am done uploading all the customers and products data on the new site Magento 1.6 then also copied and transfer the images folder to the new site using FTP.

But my problem is, I can't show all the images on the products when viewing online.

What I did is that in the Magento version 1.3 server, I copied the folder on this directory MyServer1.3/httpdocs/media/catalog/product

then transfer it to MyServer1.6/httpdocs/media/import but no luck the images were not seen.

I also trasfer it to MyServer1.6/httpdocs/media/catalog/product but still no luck, I even try this changing the folder name to MyServer1.6/httpdocs/media/catalog/import

BTW, I want to upload the clip of my .csv on importing data but I do only have 1 reputation on Stackoverflow since I'm newbie that's why I can't upload it.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you have uploaded the files with the correct permissions?

Depending on your server the owner/group permissions may need changing. Take a look at the other folders in the root (app, lib ...) and make sure the media folder has the same owner/group (substitute owner:group with the correct values)

```
chown -R owner:group media
```

Make sure access rights are correct:

**Folders: chmod 755**

**images: chmod 644**

Once this is done you should refresh image cache in the Magento admin too.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew this also helps but the problem was solved already.. I might encounter it again with different scenarios.. Thanks again!